# Submitting app to app store with xCode4 - summary of key steps - please correct/add

Tags: iphone, submit

everytime I submit a new app I spent too much time because even forgetting a small thing causes the whole process to fail. Therefore I summarized the steps that worked for me, hoping that they are correct and complete. Hope it saves some a lot of wasted time:

> - In iTunesConnect under Manage Your Applications add the new app

a.  Very important is the BundleID!

- Bundle ID com.aaa.ccccc  <- remember this BundleID

b.  Fill in all the other information

c.  Don’t forget to click on „Ready to load binary“ in the upper right corner, otherwise it will not be shown when validating or submitting under last point

> - „Create App ID“

In http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/add.action under „Create App ID“ create new AppID and use the correct BundleID in the field: „Enter a unique identifier for your App ID. The recommended practice is to use a reverse-domain name style string for the Bundle Identifier portion of the App ID.“

> - New Distribution Profile

Under Provisioning -> Distribution create a new Distribution Profile for this app http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action
 Again: use the correct BundleID in the field „APP ID“ pull down menu

> - Download and import

Download this and import in the Organizer – it's all done automatically by double-clicking on the downloaded file

> - In Xcode:

a.  In the .plist file -> use the same BundleID as defined

b.  In „Product“ -> „edit Scheme“ -> „iOS Device“ (unplug the iPhone, otherwise this option is not there)

c.  Double-click on the project blue icon to get the page where there is „PROJECT“ and „TARGET“

d.  In PROJECT: Under „Code Signing“ -> „release“ -> „any SDK“ choose the imported one with the correct BundleID

e.  In TARGET: Under „Code Signing“ -> „release“ -> „any SDK“ choose the imported one with the correct BundleID

If xCode doesn't let you select the code sign you want and the code sign is actually available in xCode, then quit xCode and restart, it will work only after this restart...

f.  I needed to do it in both, otherwise I always got a codeSign Error

g.  for the PROJECT Do NOT change the default settings in xCode -> Deployment -> Skip Install -> release -> no

h.  for the TARGET check if in xCode -> Deployment -> Skip Install -> release -> yes

i.  Still in xCode under „Product“

- -> „CLEAN“, then
- -> „Build for Archiving“
- ->“Archive“ (it will appear automatically in the Organizer)

> - In Organizer

a.  Validate the archived app against the proposed app that comes up from the drop-down proposed apps in iTunesConnect

b.  It should suggest all apps where you clicked „

That’s it...

Comment: Thanks Joe, I didn't think of that! That was it. Please state your comment as the answer, so I can check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to

## check all your version numbers!

All the best, fat Jo